# Folder for mysql ddbb working with Tomcat

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I am a student trying to develop a web page. I am using Tomcat, html, css, servlets and jsp pages. I've used mysql to create a test database.

My question is probably due to lack of a lot of background knowledge but I am stuck at this moment and cannot find an answer elsewhere.

I have my very basic test web page created, it's on Tomcat webapps folder and it works (html, css & jsp pages).

Now the question is, where should I store the database (which folder) so that Tomcat can access it?

Also, if I need to send all the web to a teacher, I would send all the "webapps\myweb...\ files, but also the database, which I cannot find in my hard drive.

Platform is Windows 7.

I apologize if this is a weird question, but I honestly have not been able to find an answer.